# why the nohup background process did not started

Tags: linux, shell, nohup

I am using this script to startup my application:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -u
set -e
set -x

nohup pdm run python3.10 /root/visa/main_api.py > /root/visa/starup.log &

tail -f /root/visa/starup.log
```

when I execute the the script as shell command in ternimal `./scripts/startup.sh`, the process did not started. But when I run the background startup command seperate in shell like this:

```
nohup pdm run python3.10 /root/visa/main_api.py > /root/visa/starup.log &
```

it works fine. why the process did not started when running in shell command? what should I do to run this background command from shell scripts?

Comment: add logging for std-err to your non-working shell invocation, ie. `nohup pdm run python3.10 /root/visa/main_api.py > /root/visa/starup.log  2>/tmp/visa_startup.stderr &` ALSO, `set -e` has very few valid use-cases. Don't put it at the top of every script, just because you saw it someplace or it "seems like a good idea". At a minimum, try commenting it out and see if that changes anything (still use `2>/tmp/..std_err` )